# Unable to get click from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm finally at the stage of building out my web pages, and I'm stuck.  I have gone through numerous pages to attempt to understand what I'm doing wrong, yet nothing is helping. Hence, I'm turning to you.  I'm certain I'm doing something bone-headed, but can't track it down.

I have built a simple login screen, and I'm attempting to get the submit button to fire a click event and show my success modal. However, when I click submit, nothing happens. There is nothing showing on the console (Dev Tools) within Chrome as well. I am getting 3 errors in the JQuery and Bootstrap components, but they make no sense.

```
*jquery-1.11.2.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*
*bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
jquery-1.11.2.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*
```

My code for my login.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="well">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td colspan="2">Login</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="text" id="txtLogin"     placeholder="Username" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="password" id="txtPassword"     placeholder="Password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success"     type="button" value="Submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="successModal" data-    keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <h4>Success</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Login Successful</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
                                Close
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
                                Close
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divError" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
                <a id="linkClose" class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div id="divErrorText"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#linkClose').click(function () {
                $('#divError').hide('fade');
            });
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                $('#successModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you the `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` anywhere else ??

Comment: like @zakaria asked. are there other pages where this version of jQuery does work?

Comment: No, the pages I was building, 3 in total, none were working. So I sent out my simple of the 3, in hopes it was something simple.

Comment: I just re-read your code and the error message. there is something that is loading a different version of jQuery than your code your code src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" but the error is showing 1.11.2. Perhaps your framework or something is also loading a different version

Comment: Nothing in the framework, this is the first instance of using JQuery. It's a brand new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery is not loading correct the file redownload or use a cdn version this sample works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#linkClose').click(function () {
                $('#divError').hide('fade');
            });
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                $('#successModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="well">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td colspan="2">Login</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="text" id="txtLogin"     placeholder="Username" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="password" id="txtPassword"     placeholder="Password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success"     type="button" value="Submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="successModal" data-    keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <h4>Success</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Login Successful</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
                                Close
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
                                Close
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divError" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
                <a id="linkClose" class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div id="divErrorText"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's nice to see it work.  I have tried the non-minified, but corporate policy doesn't allow CDNs. I did re-download, but encountered the same errors.

Comment: check the path to the file you are using because it is not loading according to the error msg

Comment: where did you download the file from? try the ones from [this page](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: I grabbed the non-mini version, and it seems to be working.  Something is not right with the minified it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Try: Try removing the minify from your script links  src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js

Comment: This was added in an attempt to get past my errors. Since finding a good version of JQuery, I've removed this section from the code.